# random_shuffle on vector produces same results with srand( time ( NULL ) ) in main.cpp

Tags: c++, eclipse, random, vector, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle a vector of ints with random shuffle, but the same sequence is returned every time. I have added an srand( time (NULL ) ) in the main cpp file, this does nothing. I have tried adding the srand function to the global body of the shuffleclass class, this did not help either.

Code:

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : random_shuffle_example.cpp
// Author      : Edwin Rietmeijer
// Version     :
// Copyright   : This code is owned by Edwin Rietmeijer as of 2014
// Description : Hello World in C++, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include "ShuffleClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand( time ( NULL ) );
    ShuffleClass * shuffleObject = new ShuffleClass;
    shuffleObject -> shuffle();
    shuffleObject -> toScreen();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/*
 * ShuffleClass.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 20, 2014
 *      Author: edwinrietmeijer
 */

#ifndef SHUFFLECLASS_H_
#define SHUFFLECLASS_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>

class ShuffleClass {
private:
    const static int numbersToShuffle[];
    std::vector<int> myvector;
public:
    ShuffleClass();
    void shuffle();
    void toScreen();
    virtual ~ShuffleClass();
};

#endif
```

---

```
/*
 * ShuffleClass.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 20, 2014
 *      Author: edwinrietmeijer
 */

#include "ShuffleClass.h"

const int ShuffleClass::numbersToShuffle[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

ShuffleClass::ShuffleClass() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        ShuffleClass::myvector.push_back( numbersToShuffle[ i ] );
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

void ShuffleClass::shuffle() {
    std::random_shuffle( ShuffleClass::myvector.begin(), ShuffleClass::myvector.end() );
}

void ShuffleClass::toScreen() {
    std::vector<int>::iterator pos;
    for ( pos = myvector.begin(); pos != myvector.end(); ++pos )
        std::cout << *pos << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


ShuffleClass::~ShuffleClass() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

Comment: Methinks you pasted your `main()` source twice rather than including once-each your `main()` source and `ShuffleClass.h` header.

Comment: In c++11 don't use random_shuffle. Simply use shuffle. It is new and it takes advantage of c++11 random facilities. Try and give us feedback, who knows :)

Comment: but,It works in my compiler.

Comment: I use the standard compiler in Eclipse, I am guessing I need to add some attributes somewhere in my project properties to compile in c++11?

Comment: Regarding using `std::shuffle` [See It Live](http://ideone.com/wgD2SZ). It honestly is preferred for a C++11 impl. When in doubt use a bigger hammer.